# What is the meaning of this Error

Tags: mysql, database

my query is :

```
include ('../set/connect.php');
mysql_query("set names utf8");
$p=sprintf("INSERT INTO `bayegani`.`tbl_bayegani` (, `number`, `date_send`, `num_rs`, `date_rs`, `year`, `word`, `subject`, `num_py`, `date_py`, `comp`, `user_sn`, `mahal`, `address`, `catg`, `type`, `peyvast`, `page`, `ext`, `file1`, `file2`, `file3`, `file4`) 

VALUES ( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s');"

,$_POST['number'],$_POST['date_send'],$_POST['num_rs'],$_POST['date_rs'],$_POST['year']
,$_POST['word'],$_POST['subject'],$_POST['num_py'],$_POST['date_py'],$_POST['comp'],
$_POST['user_sn'],$_POST['mahal'],$_POST['address'],$_POST['catg'],$_POST['type'],$_POST['peyvast']
,$_POST['page'],$_POST['ext'],$_POST['file1'],$_POST['file2'],$_POST['file3'],$_POST['file4']);

mysql_query($p);


header("location:index.php");
```

and the error is :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' `number`, `date_send`, `num_rs`, `date_rs`, `year`, `word`, `subject`, `num_py`' at line 1

What's the problem?
Please help
Thanks

Comment: `(,` <- syntax error

Comment: and for the millionth time: stop using PHP's deprecated mysql API

Comment: Why bother writing any code if your tables get dropped by users

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the initial comma (,) before `number` column name.

```
$p=sprintf("INSERT INTO `bayegani`.`tbl_bayegani` (`number`, `date_send`, `num_rs`, `date_rs`, `year`, `word`, `subject`, `num_py`, `date_py`, `comp`, `user_sn`, `mahal`, `address`, `catg`, `type`, `peyvast`, `page`, `ext`, `file1`, `file2`, `file3`, `file4`)   //Removed the comma before `number`
```

Answer (score -1):

The error code its pretty clear

> you have an error in your SQL syntax... near 'number'

if you look where have you put `number` you will see an extra `,` that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Sorry, the " , " was the error. My mistake. I'll edit it